# Test function for adding 2 numbers

Tags: testing

A couple of days ago I had an interview for an internship and I've been asked to write a function that tests if another function (which was adding 2 numbers together) is working. My answer was something similar to this:

```
bool addTest(double a, double b){

    if((a+b) == addFunction(a, b))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

However, they did not seem impressed with my answer. How else could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test cases should be written with parameters and expected answers hard coded into them to eliminate any uncertainty.

```
bool addTest(){

  //2+2=4
  if (addfunction(2,2) !=4){
    return false;
  }

  //1.66666+7.9=9.56666
  if (addFunction(1.66666, 7.9) != 9.56666){
    return false;
  }

  //0+0=0
  if (addFunction(0,0) != 0){
    return false;
  }

//all tests passed
return true;
}
```

If a bug is found later on in the development, the conditions that caused the bug should be added to the test function. For example, one day you try to add two negative numbers, only to find they return a positive number. Adding a test case for this will ensure this bug is caught again if the function changes in the future.

```
//addFunction(-8, -1) //Oops! We return positive 9! Let's fix the bug and make a new test
//-8 + -1 = -9
if (addFunction(-8, -1) != -9){
  return false;    
}
```

It also wouldn't hurt to add test cases that verify two values don't produce a **wrong** answer, though this is harder to cover all test cases.

```
//-8 + -1 = -9
if (addFunction(-8, -1) == 9){
  return false;    
}
```